# Custom Watermarked Textbox behaving strangely

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, custom-controls

## SOLUTION:

Thanks to [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658428/custom-watermarked-textbox-behaving-strangely/658613#658613) below, I have refactored the C# CodeProject version into a VB.NET version that works for me. Hopefully it can help you guys as well:

```
Partial Public Class WatermarkedTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Private _waterMarkColor As Color = Color.LightGray
    Public Property WaterMarkColor() As Color
        Get
            Return _waterMarkColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            _waterMarkColor = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _waterMarkText As String = "Watermark"
    Public Property WaterMarkText() As String
        Get
            Return _waterMarkText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _waterMarkText = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Sub New()

    End Sub
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnCreateControl()
        MyBase.OnCreateControl()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        Const WM_PAINT As Integer = &HF
        If m.Msg = WM_PAINT Then
            If Text.Length <> 0 Then
                Return
            End If
            Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
                g.DrawString(WaterMarkText, Me.Font, New SolidBrush(WaterMarkColor), 0, 0)
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
        Invalidate()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLostFocus(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLostFocus(e)
        Invalidate()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnFontChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnFontChanged(e)
        Invalidate()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnGotFocus(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        '' added so the watermark is not cleared until text is entered
        MyBase.OnGotFocus(e)
        Invalidate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

I am building a kiosk application, and in order to keep it aesthetically pleasing I decided to implement a watermarked textbox as the entry fields.  I found [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/WaterMark.aspx) on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/), converted it over to VB.NET and put it into my application.  It works, in the sense that it watermarks and clears them just fine, but when I go to enter text this happens:

Empty:

[image]

Filled:

[image]

So basically it is not clearing the whole watermark, just the space appropriated for the default height of a textbox.  here is the converted code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing


Partial Public Class WatermarkedTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
    Private oldFont As Font = Nothing
    Private waterMarkTextEnabled As Boolean = False

#Region "Attributes"
    Private _waterMarkColor As Color = Color.LightGray
    Public Property WaterMarkColor() As Color
        Get
            Return _waterMarkColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            _waterMarkColor = value
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _waterMarkText As String = "Water Mark"
    Public Property WaterMarkText() As String
        Get
            Return _waterMarkText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _waterMarkText = value
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region

    Public Sub New()
        JoinEvents(True)
    End Sub  
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnCreateControl()
        MyBase.OnCreateControl()
        WaterMark_Toggle(Nothing, Nothing)
    End Sub
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal args As PaintEventArgs)
        'Dim drawFont As New System.Drawing.Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, Font.Style, Font.Unit)
        Dim drawFont As New Font("Arial", 28, FontStyle.Bold) 'New System.Drawing.Font(oldFont.FontFamily, oldFont.Size, oldFont.Style, oldFont.Unit)
        Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(WaterMarkColor)
        args.Graphics.DrawString((If(waterMarkTextEnabled, WaterMarkText, Text)), drawFont, drawBrush, New PointF(0.0F, 0.0F))
        MyBase.OnPaint(args)
    End Sub

    Private Sub JoinEvents(ByVal join As Boolean)
        If join Then
            AddHandler Me.TextChanged, AddressOf WaterMark_Toggle
            AddHandler Me.LostFocus, AddressOf Me.WaterMark_Toggle
            AddHandler Me.FontChanged, AddressOf Me.WaterMark_FontChanged
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub WaterMark_Toggle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)
        If Me.Text.Length <= 0 Then
            EnableWaterMark()
        Else
            DisableWaterMark()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub EnableWaterMark()
        oldFont = New System.Drawing.Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, Font.Style, Font.Unit)
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        Me.waterMarkTextEnabled = True
        Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisableWaterMark()
        Me.waterMarkTextEnabled = False
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, False)
        If oldFont IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(oldFont.FontFamily, oldFont.Size, oldFont.Style, oldFont.Unit)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub WaterMark_FontChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)
        If waterMarkTextEnabled Then
            oldFont = New System.Drawing.Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, Font.Style, Font.Unit)
            Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I attempted to force the class to use my set font size in the OnPaint event, but no luck with that. Is there something else that I am missing that is making this more difficult than it should be?

Thanks!

Comment: Glad that worked Anders.  It might help you also to refactor the watermark drawing as follows: g.DrawString(WaterMarkText, Me.Font, New SolidBrush(WaterMarkColor), 0, 0)

Comment: Cool thanks for adding that in, Colors have more options than Brushes :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing a Refresh at the end of the DisableWaterMark sub:

```
Private Sub DisableWaterMark()
    Me.waterMarkTextEnabled = False
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, False)
    If oldFont IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(oldFont.FontFamily, oldFont.Size, oldFont.Style, oldFont.Unit)
    End If
    Refresh()
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Rather than using the UserPaint control style, you can handle the WM_PAINT message in WndProc, and only print the watermark if the text is empty.  The result is basically the same though.

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    Const WM_PAINT As Integer = &HF
    If m.Msg = WM_PAINT Then
        If Text.Length <> 0 Then
            Return
        End If
        Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
            g.DrawString("Water Mark", Me.Font, Brushes.LightGray, 0, 0)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
    Invalidate()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLostFocus(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLostFocus(e)
    Invalidate()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnFontChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnFontChanged(e)
    Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok that solved part of the problem, the watermark clears now! However, the font keeps sticking to the default 8pt Microsoft Sans Serif font, even though I explicitly set the font in the declaration of the TextBox.

Comment: That comment was in regards to you pointing out what was missing in the DisableWaterMark sub. testing out this new method, will report back soon.

Comment: Excellent, I removed the original method and replaced it with yours. Works like a champ.  I will update the post with the finalized version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is something [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/TextBoxHint.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/PromptedTextBox.aspx) that could maybe help you